# Permission to remove an Amazon EC2 resource. Whats to choose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to ensure that no more than one person in its admin group has permanent permission to remove an amazon EC2 resource. There should be no modifications to the current Admin group policy. What should I use? Managed policy? STS? Maybe an Inline policy?

Comment: By person, you presumably mean an IAM user. If it's one specific IAM user then you can attach a custom policy to that IAM user that gives the additional permissions (or add that single IAM user to some new IAM group that no other IAM user will be a member of)..

Comment: Are you saying that you have an existing IAM Group called "Admin" and there are multiple IAM Users that are members of that IAM Group, and that IAM Group has permissions to Terminate Amazon EC2 instances? If your goal is to then _remove_ permissions from members of that IAM Group, then you would either need to modify the policy attached to that IAM Group, or remove members from the IAM Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new policy policy where you want include the ec2 action to terminate an instance and allow only one user to be able to do that by adding a condition.

Example :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1656720238220",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:TerminateInstances"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:* ",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:username": "johndoe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This this explicitly denies all but johndoe you wont have to edit the original admin policy even if it allows ec2 instances to terminate because of how AWS works through policies https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html